# OpenGL GLSL: Unable to blur a solid color quad

Tags: opengl, glsl, gaussian

I have written a blurring `fragment shader` which uses the standard **`Gaussian Blur`** by assigning weights to the nearby pixels (I have a `3x3 Convolution Matrix` and all elements sum up to 1.0). It works well with all the images along with all the blur size and intensity adjustments working well!

The issue is that when I render a solid colored (say Red (`RGB`(255,0,0))) quad into a texture (using an `FBO` in `OpenGL`) and try blurring using the same `fragment shader` I am using to blur images loaded from a file, I am getting back the same colored(Red in this case) solid quad without any blur.

I think why this issue occurs is because I am essentially trying to add up nearby pixels which have the exact same value, so even after weighted averaging, they average out to the same color.

Can somebody suggest me other techniques to `blur`? Especially when an image/collection of pixels has/have a very low contrast?

Comment: Are you blurring x and y in one go ? It will be better if you separate it in two passes. Also you can down scale output because you are basically reducing the data with averaging.  It might take couple of iterations before you will have sensible blur.

Comment: @JAre  No, I am doing a two-pass blur, each of the two directions once. I will try increasing the intensity of the blur.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve good effect without iterating bluer couple of times. If you make it too strong in one pass you will get artifacts (edge doubling)  take for example Photoshop, their filter also has number of iterations settings.

Comment: `"... they average out to the same color"` - This is essentially what's happening and repeating or changing sigma on the gaussian won't change that. What do you expect blurring of a single color to look like?

Comment: @beaker Imagine yourself looking at a line (made off a single color) so close to the eye, that it blurs because you simply can't focus. How do I achieve that then?

Comment: You can blur a single line because there are edges between the read part and whatever color is outside the line. In a uniformly colored quad, there is no difference in color to combine for a blur. Try this: before you blur your quad, put a white border around it with width equal to half the size of your kernel (rounded down).